# Would the EmDrive be muktzeh on Shabbos?

Tags: shabbat, muktzeh

Would the EmDrive be muktzeh on Shabbos.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RF_resonant_cavity_thruster

Comment: It would depend how the radiation is created and what the electricity does. Also light and heat (even if it is an unwanted byproduct) might be produced and considered like aish.

Comment: How can anyone answer this if the thing hasn't been invented yet?

Comment: therefore most scientists believe the EmDrive to be impossible. Many physicists have labeled the EmDrive as "pseudoscience.

Comment: Could you [edit] in a brief description of what it is, instead of relying on a link?  Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Yes. Such a device would necessarily be an extremely sensitive (and probably costly) instrument (the slightest misalignment of its parts renders it useless), and would therefore be *muktzeh mechamas chisaron kis*.